# Taking too much time to load TreeGrid in Extjs4

Tags: extjs4

Actually i am facing a problem that i amnot sure from where it is? as i am new to Extjs

I am using TreeGrid of Extjs4. I have a combobox, where i have to select an option and do a search operation.on search it will populates the TreeGrid.

But the problem i am getting when i have a huge xml files that i need to populate in to TreeGrid. Its taking toomuch time. So can anyone help me on this please to identify what may the problem?

Where as in the case small xml file it is working good.

Answer (score 1):

I too have found problem with loading large files. If your files are too large dont stick with XML.
Try to use JSON format. it will perform better with large files.
To read XML you need to parse it, read the nodes, attributes, and child nodes in the XML document, and then use the data that you’ve found.

With JSON it’s easy to get at the data since its already native javascript. No parsers or proxies necessary–all you need to do is loop through the data, fast and simple.
http://think2loud.com/680-json-xml/

Comment: Thanks Buddy. as you said me to get the response in json format, i did that but still i am facing the same problem. 

also what is happening ,when i am firing the request for first time i am getting response in around 20secs. 

second time if i am firing the same request my browser is getting hang. this is an serious issue i am facing. please help me on this.

Comment: check the parameters you passed second time, and include code on , how you are fetching your store

Comment: Both the time i am passing the same parameters. like for ex: suppose you have a combobox named 'Gender' , u select an item called 'male' from there and after that you are firing a request to get name,empId of all the Person in your organisation with gender:male. so you are getting some 1000 data in json format. 
I am having issue when again i am selecting the same option and i am firing a request.i am using restfull web service in java. easily i am getting a json. on Ext side in store i am using the reader type:json,